# validation Cast to Number failed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Im getting validation error at path badgeid, why am i getting this when my getting it when badgeid is a number, and what im saving is a number?`

Checks that i already checked:

`achievement` value is 5,

`achievement` type is Number

error:

```
(node:8260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: achievement_users validation failed: badgeid: Cast to Number failed for value "{ badgeid: 0,
  progress: 0,
  _id: 5c94c04a758c8a204440499e }" at path "badgeid"
```

save code:

```
  var achievement = new achivementUsers();
            achievement.badgeid = achievement;
            return achievement.save().then(function (response) {
```

schema:

```
{
    badgeid: {type: Number, default: 0},
    progress: {type: Number, default: 0},
    completed: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    userid: {type: String, default: 'No name'},

}
```

Comment: you are making a circular object with achievement.badgeid = achievement;
which surely will not match schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the variable `achievement`. You are setting `achievement` with the new model so you need to use another name instead:

```
  //somewhere in the code `achievement` is 5
  var achievementUser = new achivementUsers();
  achievementUser.badgeid = achievement;
  return achievementUser.save().then(function (response) {});
```

Or you can initialize the value when you create the model object. But it is still a good practice to use different variable names for different context.

```
 //somewhere in the code `achievement` is 5
  var achievement = new achivementUsers({
    badgeid: achievement
  });
  return achievement.save().then(function (response) {});
```